# Ubuntu phone development, where to start?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I'm a long time Ubuntu desktop user, but new to the development world.
I'd like to start getting myself familiar with Ubuntu Touch and learn how to develop apps for it, however I'm a little bit lost on where to start.

Can someone point me in the right direction? 
Also, do I need to get myself a device like the Nexus 4, or is sufficient to use an emulator?

Thanks

Comment: Start here http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to get one of the supported devices (However, it is still possible to use an emulator):

> -Galaxy Nexus
>   -Nexus 4
>   -Nexus 7 (2012)
>   -Nexus 10

Then you can install Ubuntu Touch by following the [guides here.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install) After that, [look here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/) for guides on how to develop your first application for Ubuntu Touch.